# Variable Wont Change

Tags: java, exception

I have to make sure I include statements to handle exceptions, but when I do, the variable Amount does not change. Help?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    AmwayTickets run = new AmwayTickets();
    System.out.print(run.ticketAmount());
}

public int ticketAmount(){
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of tickets you wish to purchase: ");
    int amount = 0;
    try {
        amount = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid Amount");
        ticketAmount();
        return amount;
    }
    if (amount < 0){
        System.out.println("Invalid Amount");
        ticketAmount();
        return amount;
    }   
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: do you want it to change? Should it change if nextInt throws an exception, meaning that something went wrong?

Comment: What are you asking? Elaborate on what you are trying to do,  what you're expecting, what is confusing you.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you should use recursion to solve this? Even if you're supposed to do this, your recursion call is in error since you're not assigning the value returned to the amount variable before returning amount. i.e.,

```
    amount = ticketAmount(); // note the difference
    return amount;
```

or more simply still:

```
    return ticketAmount();
```

But I suggest that you not do this. If this were my code, I'd use a simple while loop instead.

```
boolean amountCorrect = false;
while (!amountCorrect) {
   try {
      // try to get an assign amount
      // if successful, assign amountCorrect = true; on the next line
   } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      // give error warning here
   }
}
```

Comment: The while loop didn't work for me for some reason... I must not have done it right. The first suggestion worked great though, thank you so much!

Comment: @user1695758: the first suggestion is a bad one and was made just to show you why your code wasn't working, but is not something that I recommend that you do. Please show us your while loop attempt as an edit to your original post, and let's see if we can help you to get this to work correctly.